# Error:(45) *** Android NDK: Aborting . Stop

Tags: android, android-ndk

When I try to add to my android.mk this part:

```
#opencv
OPENCVROOT:= C:\OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk ,
```

I'm starting to get these errors;

```
Error:(45) *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop. 

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
> Process 'command 'C:/Users/alper/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

What's wrong? Please anyone help me.